# How to send email in code Igniter. What is the error in below code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<?php  
class Hello extends CI_Controller  {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->library('email'); // load the library
    }
    function index()  {
        $this->sendEmail();  
    }
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 25,
        'smtp_user' => 'suman5571@gmail.com', // change it to yours
        'smtp_pass' => 'not real password', // change it to yours
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $message = '';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n" );
        $this->email->from('suman5571@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
        $this->email->to('jagdeep.think360@gmail.com');// change it to yours
        $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
        $this->email->message($message);
        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo 'Email sent.';
        }
        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this is PHP, and please describe the Problem

Comment: Please print the output here and beatufy please :  show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Comment: An Error Was Encountered

Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

From: <suman5571@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <suman5571@gmail.com>
Reply-To: "suman5571@gmail.com" <suman5571@gmail.com>
X-Sender: suman5571@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <54606bee2a600@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Resume_from_JobsBuddy_for_your_Job_posting?=

Comment: I just loged in to your gmail account :D

Comment: yea Not to worry.. I already have changed that.. And thanks to informing it to me..

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to change the smtp host and the port must be 465

```
<?php  
    class Hello extends CI_Controller  {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();  
            $this->load->library('email'); // load the library
        }
        function index()  {
            $this->sendEmail();  
        }
        public function sendEmail()
        {
       $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
       'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
       'smtp_port' => 465,
       'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
       'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
       'mailtype' => 'html',
       'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

            $message = '';
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n" );
            $this->email->from('suman5571@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
            $this->email->to('jagdeep.think360@gmail.com');// change it to yours
            $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
            $this->email->message($message);
            if($this->email->send())
            {
                echo 'Email sent.';
            }
            else
            {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: if you want to send it also through yahoo just add this line to your smtp host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com;smtp.yahoomail.com" or any mailing sites you want to send mail's just dont forget the semi-colon :) cheers!

Comment: Yea i replaced smtp_host by 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com' ..but not working.. Same error Please solve this issue.

Comment: Error is :A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1553

Comment: I would like to inform you. i am testing it on localhost. Will it work on localhost??

Comment: yeah you have to enable openssl in your localhost @JagdeepKaur

Comment: if your using xampp or wamp you must open php.ini and remove the semicolon to:

;extension=php_openssl.dll
If you don't have that line, check that you have the file (In my PC is on D:\xampp\php\ext) and add this to php.ini in the "Dynamic Extensions" section:

extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: if this help you out sir please accept this as an answer :) cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your effort :) ..Below code is working on live site:public function sendEmail()
        {    
   $message = 'My demo message';
   $this->load->library('email');
   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n" );
   $this->email->from('suman5571@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
   $this->email->to('jagdeep.think360@gmail.com');// change it to yours
   $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
   $this->email->message($message);
   if($this->email->send())
   {
    echo 'Email sent.';
   }
   else
   {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
   }
  }